# Visual studio code debugger does not show plots

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I have issue with visual studio code. At debugging mode i don't see plots any more. Previously i could see how plots are created before calling plt.show() (I could see how vertical lines are added in every iteration, patches etc)

Now i need to use plt.pause(1) to see it. Seeing plots was very useful but seems that nobody knew about this functionality.. Maybe you know what is wrong ?

Comment: It might not work. Please file an issue at github.com/microsoft/ptvsd .

Comment: user10403681. As Brett mentioned you can file an issue at the above location to get in direct touch with the team. If you could (either here or in a GitHub issue) detail your scenario a bit more I'm sure that we could look into it. I can tell that you are looking at building up an interactive plot, but I'm not fully sure about your use scenario here. A code sample and an idea of the output that you expect would be very helpful for diagnosing this.